# SAS PROC SQL Error Expecting a From

Tags: sql, sas

I'm using SAS PROC SQL and getting an "ERROR 79-322: Expecting a FROM." even though I have a FROM in my code.

My code is as follows:

```
proc sql;
    create table final as 
    select cusip3.*, orig2.*, 
    from cusip3 full join orig2 on cusip3.gvkey=orig2.gvkey
    where not missing(cusip3.gvkey) and not missing(orig2.gvkey)
    order by cusip3.gvkey;
quit;
```

Comment: you should remove comma after `orig2.*`

Comment: When you see errors of this nature, check before the FROM statement for things that don't look right.

Comment: Thanks Bagin and Reeza!

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma `','` before the `from` clause.

Most common causes for `"ERROR 79-322: Expecting a FROM."` are missing or extra commas.